# would 「なんとか」 be an acceptable replacement for "something"?

Tags: phrases

like as an example: 
if i forgot the name of a song but i remembered part of it, so i said "zenryoku something" (i say something because i don't know what comes after zenryoku), would 「全力」なんとか be an appropriate translation?

sorry if i tagged this wrong, this is my first time asking on this forum.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, 「なんとか」 is often used as a replacement word when the actual word has slipped one's mind.

「全力{ぜんりょく}なんとか」 is what you would say when you cannot remember the word that follows the 「全力」.  You can use it the exact same way you would use "something" in English.

Informally and/or colloquially, some people use 「なんちゃら」 for the same purpose.

You will also hear 「なにがし」 at times almost exclusively replacing parts of proper nouns.  「なにがし」 is not informal.

Finally, I would like to introduce the whole other usage of the replacement 「なんとか」 that I feel would be important for Japanese-learners to be familiar with.  That is 「なんとか」 used for a "replacement" for the word that you so clearly remember.  It is used for replacing a word in a well-known saying for ***euphemism***.

Original vs. なんとか-version.

・「**バカ**のひとつ覚{おぼ}え」⇒「**なんとか**のひとつ覚え」 ("One who knows little often repeats it".)

・「**ブタ**に真珠{しんじゅ}」⇒「**なんとか**に真珠」 ("Cast not pearls before swine.")