# use of "やらってか" in this phrase

Tags: abbreviations

> mc「洗濯物？　俺別にその辺に置いといてもらえればそのまま着るけど」
>
> girl 「だめ、ちゃんと畳むの」
>
> mc「それよりまずメシ……」
>
> girl「これが終わったら作ってあげる♪」
>
> mc 働かざるものなんとやらってか。

I'm pretty sure this is analogous to this [saying](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%83%8D%E3%81%8B%E3%81%96%E3%82%8B%E8%80%85%E9%A3%9F%E3%81%86%E3%81%B9%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%81%9A), so "no folding, no food" of some sorts

but i'm not sure what やらってか is abbreviated from

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40589/5010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 働かざるものなんとやらってか。

＝

> 『働かざるものなんとやら』ってか。

First, 「なんとやら」 means the same thing as 「なんとか」.

I explained the use of the replacement 「なんとか」 here:

[would 「なんとか」 be an acceptable replacement for "something"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/60834/would-%e3%81%aa%e3%82%93%e3%81%a8%e3%81%8b-be-an-acceptable-replacement-for-something/60837#60837)

Just like the two examples I gave at the end of that Q&A, 「なんとやら」 here is replacing the 「食{く}うべかざる」 part of the famous saying 「働{はたら}かざる者食うべからず」("He who does not work, neither shall he eat.")

「ってか」 is a colloquial way of saying 「～～ということか」.  The 「と/って」 is the quotative particle.

「～～～ってか。」, therefore, means "Are you implying to say ~~~?", "~~~, you mean?"